# Programmatically registering a Sharepoint 2007 event handler

Tags: sharepoint, event-handling

I have an event handler for the ItemAdding event of a document library.  However, I cannot get it to handle the event unless I register the event handler using the Sharepoint Event Handler Manager.  This is fine on a development server, but moving to production, I'd like to be able to register it programatically.  Is there a way to do this without using the Sharepoint Event Handler Manager?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [There is U2U-published tool for this](http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/Patrick/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=1547) but I am not sure if the source code/a good explanation of internals is available.

Comment: can't you simply package it in a feature ? for deployment, it's quite straightforward...

Comment: @Steve - do you have a reference on how to do this in Sharepoint 2007? Thanks

Comment: the entry point is in this [msdn section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460929(office.12).aspx) of the SP 2007 SDK. Basically, you create in an assembly the event receiver class, then you create a feature xml file to bind the event to a kind of list or content type. Finally, you package the whole thing in a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to bind the receiver using SharePoint API? Here is the MSDN example:

- [Binding an Event Handler by Using the SharePoint Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407249.aspx)

Comment: Sure, it should work with 2007 as well. Here is the documentation for that version and I see no difference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceiverdefinition(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Cool.. so can I put this code in my ItemAdded event handler or do I need to create a separate feature?

Comment: You definitelly can't put it in the event receiver :)  The event receiver will fire only if it is bound, and the code is used to bind an event receiver. I you can add a new feature, than you can bind the event receiver declaratively without this code.

Comment: what do the elements and manifest files look like for this?  Is there a good resource you could point me to?  Thanks!